# Perform dragdrop implementation after DoDragDrop method is called？WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I've been struggling with this for quite a while

My wpf application contains a list view, populated with file-names, which are located on a server.

I'm trying to implement drag and drop functionality, so the user can drag files from my application into his/her's local computer.

In order to do this, first i'm downloading the files into a temporary location, and then calling my application's DoDragDrop() method.

The problem is that I want to perform the download process only after the DoDragDrop method is called.

I've tried every event related to drag drop methods (GiveFeedback, ItemDrag, etc...) but nothing works

so basically what I need is an event, raised after the DoDragDrop is done

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current scheme is to drag a file with a special suffix, and then turn on global file monitoring to obtain the drag location of the file through monitoring.